# How do I substract a header width of 100% with px in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have this code to get the my specified header width using percentage where

CS

```
//Script Manager to set the (gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter)
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Key", "<script>MakeStaticHeaderORSA('" + Gridview1.ClientID + "', 400, 100, 27, false); </script>", false);
```

JS

```
 DivHeader.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 1.67) + '%';
```

However instead of subtracting 1.67% I would like to replace it with 16px to be more specific:
 Which I did something like below but its not working.

```
DivHR.style.width = (((parseInt(width)) + '%') - (16 +'px'));
```

Please advice on how can I use the 100% width and - px to get my ideal width,
thanks in advance

Comment: what is your width returning ?

Comment: why don't you do it with css only: `#yourDivId{ width: calc(100% - 16px)}`

Comment: Hi there sorry for my missing codes. my width is 100 which the input is coming from the CS thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below codes was th esolution to my quesiton thanks

```
  #yourDivId{ width: calc(100% - 16px)}
```